# How to I output an item value inside an anchor tag

Tags: reactjs

The data fetched from the API is stored in *GetBlogState*. In the data there is a key for Slug. I would like to output that key value inside an anchor tag so that it built a link for that specific blog post *e.g. /blog/test-1*. The following is what I'm currently working with.

```
   GetBlogState.map((item, index) => (
      <div className="h-68" key={index}>
        ..
        <h2 className="font-bold mb-5 text-xl"><a href="/blog/{item.Slug}" className="hover:underline">{ item.Title }</a></h2>
        ..
      </div>
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use literal templates (backtick).

```
<h2 className="font-bold mb-5 text-xl"><a href={`/blog/${item.Slug}`} className="hover:underline">{ item.Title }</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

In js you can use template strings to inject variables directly inside the string like below. The template strings are done using backticks, the character to the left of the 1 key on your keyboard and then ${} around the variable name:

```
   GetBlogState.map((item, index) => (
      <div className="h-68" key={index}>
        ..
        <h2 className="font-bold mb-5 text-xl"><a href=`/blog/${item.Slug}` className="hover:underline">{ item.Title }</a></h2>
        ..
      </div>
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use template literals inside curly braces.

```
<h2 className="font-bold mb-5 text-xl"><a href={`/blog/${item.Slug}`} className="hover:underline">{ item.Title }</a></h2>
```